# Cassandra Delete by Secondary Index or By Allowing Filtering

Tags: cassandra, cql

I’m trying to delete by a secondary index or column key in a table. I'm not concerned with performance as this will be an unusual query. Not sure if it’s possible? E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE user_range (
  id int,
  name text,
  end int,
  start int,
  PRIMARY KEY (id, name)
)
```

cqlsh> select * from dat.user_range where id=774516966;

```
id        | name      | end | start
-----------+-----------+-----+-------
774516966 |   0 - 499 | 499 |     0
774516966 | 500 - 999 | 999 |   500
```

I can:

```
cqlsh> select * from dat.user_range where name='1000 - 1999' allow filtering;

id          | name        | end  | start
-------------+-------------+------+-------
 -285617516 | 1000 - 1999 | 1999 |  1000
 -175835205 | 1000 - 1999 | 1999 |  1000
-1314399347 | 1000 - 1999 | 1999 |  1000
-1618174196 | 1000 - 1999 | 1999 |  1000
Blah blah…
```

But I can’t delete:

```
cqlsh> delete from dat.user_range where name='1000 - 1999' allow filtering;
Bad Request: line 1:52 missing EOF at 'allow'
cqlsh> delete from dat.user_range where name='1000 - 1999';
Bad Request: Missing mandatory PRIMARY KEY part id
```

Even if I create an index:

```
cqlsh> create index on dat.user_range (start);
cqlsh> delete from dat.user_range where start=1000;
Bad Request: Non PRIMARY KEY start found in where clause
```

Is it possible to delete without first knowing the primary key?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, deleting by using a secondary index is not supported: [CASSANDRA-5527](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5527)

Answer (score 12):

When you have your secondary index you can select all rows from that index. When you have your rows you know the primary key and can then delete the rows.

Answer (score 9):

I came here looking for a solution to delete rows from cassandra column family.
I ended up doing an INSERT and set a TTL (time to live) so that I don't have to worry about deleting it.

Putting it out there, might help someone.

Comment: it's completely different case, not an answer to question

Comment: Not the answer of the question, but you saved my day bro. Thanks!

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for this amazing input. If it stupid and it works, it ain't stupid.