# Cassandra : Delete the record based on the non primary key - Python

Tags: python, cassandra, pyspark, nosql, datastax

Table :

```
 ID      | OP_Type | Location   | 
---------+-----------------+-------
  101    |  D      | NY    |
  102    |  I      | NJ    |
  103    |  U      | CA    |
  103    |  D      | GA    |
```

Requirement: Table's primary key is ID . data need to delete based on the OP_Type column's value . Example OP_type = D. If i want to handle it through python .. how to to handle it . Please give me some suggestion forr the same .

Answer (score 1):

**About your dataset and primary key.**

If the primary key is the ID column, then you cannot have two lines containing the same id (103). There will be a single line that would have the most recent insert. But if your dataset in correct, then you need to have a compound primary key (containing the id and some other column in order to create uniqueness).

**Regarding your particular issue**

You could create a secondary index on the op_type column. Then you can do a select to get the needed rows and then run the delete. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515874/cassandra-delete-by-secondary-index-or-by-allowing-filtering) question is similar. Depending on your dataset and use cases, there are situations when [creating a index is not recommended](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useWhenIndex.html#useWhenIndex__when-no-index).

Also, [this article on secondary indexes](http://www.doanduyhai.com/blog/?p=13191) might prove valuable in order to understand them and to estimate the impact on your cluster.

**Python**

If you would like to do this on Python, I recommend starting with [Datastax's Python driver for Cassandra](https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/getting_started.html).

Comment: Understand . Thanks for your Help Horia !!

Comment: @KarthikeyanDurairaj I'm happy that I could help :)